# Can an application module also be used as a library module?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

I have a simple calculator app. It's a complete application all by itself.

I also have a more advanced calculator app that's based on the first app, but has more features. Its main Activity extends the first app's main Activity. The advanced app references quite a lot of resources and methods from the simpler app.

Getting the advanced app to build under Android Studio has been a nightmare. I've been googling and trying things blindly in the build.gradle files, but not making much progress. At first, the problem was `dependent features configured but no package id was set` (whatever that means, Google turned up no documentation.)

I got past that by tweaking the build.gradle files, and now I'm getting `Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`, but I can't find the relevant logs. It looks like the build failed because Android Studio tried to merge the AndroidManifest.xml files from the simple app and the advanced app, but I just wanted to use the manifest from the advanced app.

This is all very frustrating because I made it all work under Eclipse but now I have to move to Android Studio.

I guess my first question is: How can I tell Android Studio to just use the Android Manifest from the current project and not try to merge from the other project.

In general: can an application project serve as a library for another project, and if so how? Are there any examples?

Third question: where can I find good documentation on build.gradle?

I could attach my current build.gradle files and AndroidManifest.xml files if people need to see them, but I'm really hoping to learn enough that I can help myself.

Comment: It looks like a module cannot be both an application and a library. I do like yuanweiwork's solution of creating a gradle file that you can edit to toggle a module back and forth between library and app; it's the closest to a solution I can see. As for me, I fixed it by creating a library module and moving most of my common code into it, and now the simple and advanced calculators both use that library. I'll leave the question open in case anybody ever comes up with an answer, but I suspect that it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm the problem first：
Switch the same model in Library / application
Application ID androidmanifest conflict problem

if this is the problem, the official documents can see the channel packaging

https://developer.android.google.cn/studio/build

And I wrote you a little demo
https://github.com/yuanweiwork/lytools

I hope it can help you

Comment: Wow, you wrote a whole app just for me? Talk about going the extra mile. It looks like you have two apps in one module. I didn't know that was possible; let me play with it.

Comment: Work in progress config.gradle Changing the value of isapplication allows app2 to switch between Library and application